# Source to SoapMessage (for read UserToken)

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security

I have a code like this:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;

public class MyProvider implements Provider<Source> {

    public Source invoke(Source request) {
        SoapMessage message= ???    
    }
}
```

Now I want to extract from *request* the SoapMessage that I know is inside. Someone know how to do it????

Pay attention that I'd like to have a `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage` and not `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage`.

Truly my purpose is to read the **UserToken** from *request*, if I have a org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage I know how to do. 
But if someone know how to read it directly from Source or some other method I appreciated the same.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your UserToken is contained in the SOAP header. If this is the case must use ServiceMode "MESSAGE" to get the whole SOAP envelope, not just the body. Alternatively you could use a Handler which puts the extracted user token into the request context for further processing.